# Pyinstaller "ImportError: No module named xml.etree"

Tags: python, xml, importerror

I'm using the command : *pyinstaller --onefile fileslook.py*

Here are the imports of my **fileslook.py**

```
import os
import sys
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
sys.path.append(r"Z:\hi1\hi2\my_folder")
base_update = SourceFileLoader("extract", r"Z:\hi1\hi2\my_folder\Soft_python\extract.py").load_module()
```

import inside my **extract.py**

```
import parseFunction as scan_rfid
```

imports inside my **parseFunction**:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as open_xml
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
```

when executing the .exe, it returns the following error:

> import parseFunction as scan_rfid
>
> File "Z:\hi1\hi2\my_folder\Soft_python\parseFunction.py", line 1, in '<'module'>'
> import xml.etree.ElementTree as open_xml
>
> ImportError: No module named 'xml.etree'

My software is working properly when executing the fileslook.py with PyCharm and my virtual env.

The only thing I found when looking for un etree.py file inside my python installation is here:
**etree.py location:**
[image: etree.py location]

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is part of Standard Library. Try to specify hidden imports when compile to exe with `PyInstaller` - either as CLI argument or in the spec file. Read *Listing Hidden Imports* section [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#helping-pyinstaller-find-modules)

As it says:

> Hidden imports can also occur when an extension module uses the Python/C API to do an import

I think that's what is going on here with the way you import `extract.py`

Comment: When executing "pyinstaller -v --onefile fileslook.py" it returns "3.4" my Python version while it is supposed to list modules which are needed.
Also tried "pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=xml fileslook.py" but it seems to not work as it should

Comment: `-v` or `--version` option just print the PyInstaller version. Try `pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=xml.etree.ElementTree fileslook.py`. You can also edit the generated spec file.

Comment: by the way, once this one is resolved i think you may expect the same for `openpyxl` package

Comment: yes it worked, and you were right. Got the same for openpyxl, I guess it's gonna be easier to build a hook file which I will link in my command line

Comment: Probably you have your reasons for that complicated import scheme, but also maybe can optimize the imports.